# How can I mark tapped location in Google Maps mapview in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have MapActivity with working mapview in my application. The problem that I faced is that I want to tap any location on the map, show the dialog with text example:

```
do you want to mark this location?
```

If yes, it'll extract the coordinates and save it somewhere (that doesn't matter where right now),

how can I do that? I've tried to use dispatchTouchEvent method but I failed.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{   
if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
    GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
        (int) event.getX(),
        (int) event.getY());
        // send the intent from here to your next activity with the GeoPoint coords.
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
            p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
            p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}                      
return false;
}
```

It shows me my coordinates - but it's doing it everytime when I just touch the map - I can't even move it.

Comment: Show us what you tried and describe how it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc for [`dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) states the following:

> You can override this to intercept all touch screen events before they are dispatched to the window. Be sure to call this implementation for touch screen events that should be handled normally.

So you should handle all other events with the original method:

```
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {   
  if (event.getAction() == 1) {
    // do your stuff
    return true;
  }                      
  return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir : ] Is it possible to handle it by any other methods? I've heard and tried onTap() with overlay class, but without success. IMHO dispatchtouchevent() isn't the best way to go - am i right?

Comment: As far as I know the `onTap` method is triggered only if you tap on an item that is placed on the overlay. But there is also a method `onTouchEvent` in the Overlay class. Maybe this is an option for you.